# onPrepareSupportNavigateUpTaskStack when overriding Up navigation not called

Tags: android, appcompatactivity, up-navigation

When navigating up my parent activity requires some extras. But I'm not sure how can I supply it. AppCompatActivity's documentation states:

> If any activity
>        * along the parent chain requires extra Intent arguments, the Activity subclass
>        * should override the method {@link #onPrepareSupportNavigateUpTaskStack(android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder)}
>        * to supply those arguments.

That's what I have so far.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".user.offers.detail.OfferDetailActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:parentActivityName=".user.offers.master.OffersMasterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

There's not much information on how to override `onPrepareSupportNavigateUp`, so here's my best guess (in 'child' activity):

```
override fun onPrepareSupportNavigateUpTaskStack(builder: TaskStackBuilder) {
    builder.editIntentAt(builder.intentCount - 1)?.apply {
        putExtra(OffersMasterActivity.CAT_KEY_EXTRA, catKey)
        putExtra(OffersMasterActivity.CAT_NAME_EXTRA, catName)
        putExtra(OffersMasterActivity.CAT_PICPATH_EXTRA, picPath)
    }
}
```

But the method is never called to figure out if my implementation valid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For `onPrepareSupportNavigateUp` to be called, `supportShouldUpRecreateTask` should be overridden first returning `true`.

Comment: This worked wonderfully, but there's an unfortunate side effect when using this. A white screen appears before loading the previous activity, which makes the transition feel unnatural. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @kevinivan05, did you ever find a way to fix or at least mitigate the white screen transition issue?  I am experiencing that same unnatural transition issue after overriding these methods.  Gauging from the lack of matching results when I searched for answers to this problem or more specifically for the methods mentioned in this answer, it appears there is still a surprising lack of detailed information readily available about these methods.